# Apps inside app

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to develop an application with mini app inside it. The main application functions like an platform (OS) which allows mini apps (Software) to be installed inside it. How should I design such application?

This main application has some basic functionality while the mini app provides some additional functions.

(Update)
Included a picture for clearer information.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Managed Execution framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg315232).  It makes it easier to implement plugins.

Comment: Ya, I should have thought of the term plugins. Looking at the Managed Execution framework now

Comment: After looking at the Managed Execution Framework, I still couldn't see how it helps me in achieving what I need to do. Do you mind to give some example on this?

Comment: http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MEFlook&referringTitle=Samples

Answer (score 0):

Maybe design the main application as a sort of framework and design the other parts as modules which interact with the framework?

Comment: Could you explain more on this?

Comment: Hm...well without knowing more it's a bit difficult to know exactly the scale of what you want, but for example, you could have an application for games- it has no games on it directly but it supports basic features used by all games (highscores...maybe a deck of cards). Then when you write specific games, like solitare or poker, you'd use these aspects (highscores and cards), of course users choose to "install" those specific things onto your "game" platform.

Comment: Ya. That would be what I am looking for.